# Kernel functions

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

[image]

Shown is the kernel function $k(x,x')$ for $x'=0.$
Their point is to show the localization of kernel func. But if $x'=0$, how is it varying over space. Shouldn't the dot product be zero?

Can someone please explain the graphs in the 2nd row in the picture.This is taken from CM Bishop.

The polynomial kernel  function k(x,x') is defined as (x(trpose)*x' + c)^2

Comment: I think we need more information than this.

Comment: Hey Cameron can you let me know what else i needed?Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphs show the kernel function vary as function of x', when the similarity measure is computed for x=0 example exp(-(x-x')/2B)

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the figure, which was fixed by the authors in the book's errata. You can find the correct figure here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf